# Google Maps v3 API getting route duration fails

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Could you please explain to me why I don't get `google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK` in this piece of code?

```
function measureDistance(m1, m2) {
    var wp = new Array();
    var lstart = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[m1].position);
    var lend = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[m2].position);
    var request = {
        origin : lstart,
        destination : lend,
        waypoints : [],
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status== google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('locationD').value = "drawRouteBad";
        }

    });
}
```

`Markers` is a global dictionary with markers from the map. `directionsService` is defined globally (and the same `directionsService` works for me in another function). The problem is, that for some reason I can't get correct response (I've got drawRouteBad in one of fields on my website).

Comment: From the docs: **This property may be undefined as the duration may be unknown.**

Comment: Ok, but this line isn't running. That's what I'm trying to achieve, but what I get is drawRouteBad in one of fields on my site. So I can't get right directions for some reason.

Comment: What are the values of markers[m1].position and markers[m2].position?  Perhaps it isn't possible to find a route to drive between them.

Comment: One is: $a: 19.890596866607666
Za: 50.071739459820954 and the second: $a: 19.88997459411621
Za: 50.07978171143738. I definitely can find a route between them - in another test I use similar positions (on the same street, almost the same points) and I've got what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I don't need to create new LatLng objects. What is inside markers[].position is enough for start and end.

```
 var lstart = markers[m1].position;
 var lend = markers[m2].position;
```

Comment: It is a google.maps.LatLng.  As a warning, the .position member of the [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) is not documented and could go away at any time. The documented way to get the position of the marker is the Marker.getPosition() method.