# Qt and GoogleMaps - duration type

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use this code to getData from javascript:

```
 const QVariant myvar = this->page()->mainFrame()->
     evaluateJavaScript("measureDistance("+QString::fromStdString(prev->marker_id)+","+QString::fromStdString(stop->marker_id+");"));
 bool ok;
 const int myint = myvar.toInt(&ok);
 if (!ok)
   qWarning() << "Error getting int from JS";
 qDebug() << myint;
 getMapTimeDistance(location, QString::fromStdString(prev->getName()), stop, 10);
```

And in javascript the last line is:

```
function measureDistance(m1, m2) {
var wp = new Array();
var lstart = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[m1].position);
var lend = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[m2].position);
var request = {
    origin : lstart,
    destination : lend,
    waypoints : [],
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status== google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('locationD').value = "drawRouteBad";
    }

});
```

}

Do you know why this code won't work for me? I've tried different combinations of types, but nothing helped. Probably I don't know what type is javasscripts value. Maybe I should pass it to the qt in different way?

Answer (score 0):

`response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;` is coming from the Google Maps API v3 [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) (per [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329473/google-maps-v3-api-getting-route-duration-fails).  That service is asynchronous, you can't return anything from the call to it, you have to use any data you need inside the callback function (when it has been returned from the server and is available).

Comment: After adding the code - is it still the same issue? If so have you got any idea how to send this value to qt?